# Jest, ES6 modules "does not provide export named"

Tags: node.js, express, unit-testing, jestjs

I have an express app with a CRUD API (with sequelize) and I want to test it with Jest. I'm pretty new in unit-testing so I follow this [guide](https://www.albertgao.xyz/2017/05/24/how-to-test-expressjs-with-jest-and-supertest/), recommended by [Jest's website](https://jestjs.io/docs/testing-frameworks#expressjs).

The problem I have is that my app is built with ES6 modules and Jest ES6 modules is experimental and it seems that it doesn't "import" packages.

I have this test *(took from the guide)*

```js
import request from 'supertest';
import app from '../app';

describe('Test the root path', () => {
    test('It should response the GET method', done => {
        request(app)
            .get('/')
            .then(response => {
                expect(response.statusCode).toBe(404);
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

And when I launched it (with `NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules npx jest` I had to follow this [jest wiki page](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules)), It says that

`'sequelize' does not provide an export named 'DataTypes'` and when I launch my app normally (like with `npm start`) it works fine, without any problems.

*(the complete error log):*

```
(node:49576) ExperimentalWarning: VM Modules is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
 FAIL  __tests__/app_test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    SyntaxError: The requested module 'sequelize' does not provide an export named 'DataTypes'

      at Runtime.linkAndEvaluateModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:779:5)
      at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
      at runJest (node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:404:19)
      at _run10000 (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:320:7)
      at runCLI (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:173:3)
```

*(and my Jest config)*

```
// Sync object
/** @type {import('@jest/types').Config.InitialOptions} */

export default async () => {
    return {
        verbose: true,
        transform: {},
    };
};
```

Am I doing something wrong ? Should I change to commonJS instead of ES6

Thank you.

Comment: Import / Exports are not supported natively by Node as you may already know. Do you parse your code via babel? You can use something like `babel-jest` in that case. If it's Typscript there is `ts-jest` and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known problem in Jest: [#9771](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9771). It is said to be fixed in `jest@28.0.0-alpha.0`.

An interesting [hack](https://github.com/nfriedly/express-rate-limit/issues/267#issuecomment-1000984056) to work around this problem is to remove the `main` field from the `package.json` of the imported project.

Comment: I upgraded to Jest@28.0.3 and this fixed it for me.